# Decorators not returning function

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a school assignment involving decorators. I wrote this code:

```
def valid_input(func):
    def wrapper(x):
        if x in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
            return func(x)
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
    return wrapper

def show_operation(func):
    def wrapper(x, y):
        operation = func.__name__
        print(f"Performing {operation}")
        return func(x, y)
    return wrapper

@valid_input
def calc(op):
    if op == 0:
        print("Quitting calculator...")
        quit()
    else:
        x = get_operand()
        y = get_operand()
        if op == 1:
            return add(x, y)
        elif op == 2:
            return sub(x, y)
        elif op == 3:
            return mult(x, y)
        elif op == 4:
            return div(x, y)

def menu():
    print("Enter an operation:")
    print("1 Add\n2 Subtract\n3 Multiply\n4 Divide\n0 Quit")
    return int(input(">"))

def get_operand():
    return int(input("Enter an operand:"))

@show_operation
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@show_operation
def sub(x, y):
    return x - y

@show_operation
def mult(x, y):
    return x * y

@show_operation
def div(x, y):
    return x / y

while True:
    op = menu()
    result = calc(op)
    print(f"Result: {result}\n")
```

The problem is that if the user enters invalid input, some errors appear. It seems that my decorators aren't working correctly with their associated functions.

What is wrong with the code, and how do I fix it?

Comment: "but errors appear any time invalid input is entered" - invalid input like, say, "apple"? You don't do anything to handle a failure to convert the input to int.

Comment: I don't quite follow: **were you expecting**, for example, that the decorator could check whether an operand value is an integer? If so, which decorator do you expect to do that, and how? Separately: suppose that a function decorated with `valid_input` receives invalid input. **What do you expect to happen**? For example, what do you think the function will return? What do you expect the caller to do as a result? Why?

Comment: Your decorators work just fine for what's asked of them: the main loop will continue if the user's selection is an out-of-range number, and it will show the `Invalid Input` message and a result for the calculation of `None`. For valid inputs, `show_operation` gets used correctly, the corresponding "Performing" message appears, and then the rest of the calculation is successful.

Comment: @user2357112
I wanted to thank you for nudging me along in the correct way. I used "if op.isdigit():"  method to check whether the user input is a valid integer.  I modified my menu(), get_operand() functions, and while loop. Now the program rejects strings as well.

Answer (score -1):

The main issue here is that no exception handling is done, particularly when getting operands. What you need to do is catch the exception when it occurs:

```py
def get_operand():
    try:
        return int(input("Enter an operand:"))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")
```

Now when incorrect value is entered for an operand, the script will print a message and re-raise the Exception. Technically, you could handle exception right then and there with `pass` but it's usually better to propagate exceptions to the main function so that the end user can decide what they want to do with them.

So now, you need to also modify your `while` loop to handle the exception when it comes up:

```
while True:
    op = menu()
    try:
        result = calc(op)
        print(f"Result: {result}\n")
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Chaining the exception without adding a message or changing the exception type seems pointless. Why not just `raise`?

Comment: Agree, fixed it.